# Connecting Multiple Dayton Tactile Transducers to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio-interfaces, amplifier, electronics

I'm working on a project where I need to connect four Dayton Audio TT25-8 Puck Tactile Transducers to a Raspberry Pi. The goal is to have each transducer play a separate audio track simultaneously. Is this possible? What would be the best way to do this?

I'm thinking I would need not only an amplifier but also an audio interface, since I would need 4 separate channels that the Pi could communicate with. I'm looking for a budget friendly way to do this, so I was thinking of buying two audio interfaces, although I'm not sure if that would work. These 4 channel amplifiers and audio interfaces are super expensive so I am wondering if there's another way about this. Thanks!

Heres the bass shaker: [image: bass shaker]

Comment: If you want them to play four different signals they will each need their own channel of amplification. There’s no way around that. Then each amplifier channel will need its own input signal. Whether you get two stereo amps and two stereo interfaces or one quad amp and one quad interface or some other combination, four separate signals means four separate channels all the way through the system.

Comment: This is exactly what you're asking for - https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/multiple-sounds-simultaneously-raspberry-pi/